# Simpler alternative for accessing master object from nested listview on XAF

Tags: c#, listview, nested, viewcontroller, xaf

I want to know if there is simple and clear method other than this for accessing master object from a nested listview controller.

```
((PropertyCollectionSource)((ListView)View).CollectionSource).MasterObject
```

Do I have to write this in everywhere where i need to access master object?

I think this is not an elegant way and looks so lame.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not tested yet, but you can use the following ViewController descendant:

```
public class NestedViewController : ViewController
{
    protected PropertyCollectionSource PropertyCollectionSource
    {
        get
        {
            return View is ListView ? ((ListView)View).CollectionSource is PropertyCollectionSource ? ((ListView)View).CollectionSource as PropertyCollectionSource : null : null;
        }
    }

    protected object MasterObject
    {
        get
        {
            return PropertyCollectionSource != null ? PropertyCollectionSource.MasterObject : null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thx, that can be useful of course. so not many alternatives, right?

Comment: Yeah not so many alternatives, but if you inherit from this class instead of ViewController class, will make it clean and fast.

Answer (score 1):

Simplifying the above answer with C#6

```
public partial class NestedViewController : ViewController
{
    protected PropertyCollectionSource PropertyCollectionSource => (View as ListView)?.CollectionSource as PropertyCollectionSource;

    protected object MasterObject => PropertyCollectionSource?.MasterObject;
}
```

Also I moved it into a function

```
public static class HandyControllerFunctions
{
    public static object GetMasterObject(View view)
    {
        var propertyCollectionSource = (view as ListView)?.CollectionSource as PropertyCollectionSource;
        return propertyCollectionSource?.MasterObject ;
    }
}
```

and call it for example

var myObject = HandyControllerFunctions.GetMasterObject(View) as IMyObject